# How to confirm user without confirm code in AWS Cognito User Pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

There is a registration by invite codes in my application. I store invite codes in database. Registration form has fields: username, email, password, invite code. I have Pre-SignUp lambda function that checks if invite code is wrong then it set:

```
event.response.autoConfirmUser = false;
```

If invite code is correct then:

```
event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
```

So user is registered anyway, but if invite code is incorrect then user is unconfirmed. Then I need to confirm existing user by invite code. [ConfirmSignUp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ConfirmSignUp.html) needs confirm code but I don's have confirm code. Is there a method to confirm user without confirm code? I could use lambda function for confirming user by invite code